# Is there a single word that can represent "lingering fear"?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Lingering fear" is when after a fearful/traumatic experience, you still have some fright remaining despite there are no more dangers. I was wondering if there's any single word that can possibly represent this?

Comment: It's not exactly a "word", but [PTSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder) is only four characters. And probably if there *had* been a shorter alternative to the full four-word original, they'd have gone for that in the first place.

Comment: I don't know any specific word for this **trauma**

Comment: If you don't like PTSD, try *aversion*.

Answer (score 2):

***Residual Fear, vestigial and impending;***

If the fear is pathological, then the given answers, **neurosis** (Charon) and **PTSD** (Centaurus   ) would be best to describe the psychological trauma.

But the fear experienced in everyday life may be unpleasant but not damaging. Such fear, if it is a vestige, is experienced as  *(Oxford definitions)*

> '[**disquiet**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disquiet),'
>   '[**perturbation**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/perturbation)(the state of
>   feeling anxious about something that has happened),'
>   '[**haunting**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/haunting) (beautiful, sad or **frightening** in a way that
>   cannot be forgotten).'

If there is also menace of the fear returning there is,  *(Merriam-Webster definitions)*

> '**[foreboding](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreboding)**(presentiment especially of coming evil),'
>   '**[trepidation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trepidation)**(: a feeling of fear that causes you to hesitate
>   because you think something bad or unpleasant is going to happen),'
>   '**[edginess](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edginess)**'( characterized by tension) may be experienced.

Clearly a widespread experience, and there are many shades of meaning to choose from.

Comment: Also *unease*.  Good list.

Answer (score 1):

Dread? That emotion is often based on a previous experience,although it can relate to future possible events.

Comment: _Dread_ occurred to me, too, but I was put off by its emphasis on fear of something impending rather than on residual fear about something that has already occurred but continues to linger in the mind.

Answer (score 0):

The best term for that condition, as mentioned above by FF, is **PTSD** which stands for "post-traumatic stress disorder".  The term describes exactly what you mentioned and there is no single and specific word for that.

> - Posttraumatic stress disorder is an anxiety disorder that can develop after a person is exposed to one or more traumatic events, such as major stress, sexual assault, warfare, or other threats on a person's life.  Symptoms include disturbing recurring flashbacks, avoidance or numbing of memories of the event, and hyperarousal, continue for more than a month after the occurrence of a traumatic event. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder)

Answer (score -1):

I think that ***[neurosis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neurosis)*** fits your requirements quite well.

> - A relatively mild mental illness that is not caused by organic disease, involving symptoms of stress (depression, anxiety, obsessive behaviour, hypochondria) but not a radical loss of touch with reality.
> - (in non-technical use) excessive and irrational anxiety or obsession.

Whilst it isn't exactly synonymous with 'lingering fear', I think that someone who did have a recalcitrant, irrational fear could be said to be neurotic.

Comment: Heh, what word means "radical loss of touch with reality"?

Comment: Good question. I'd guess *psychosis*.

Answer (score -1):

**phobia**: an extreme or irrational fear of or aversion to something.

(In your case, I guess it would be *irrational* more than *extreme*.)